# Ширина flex элемента по его содержимому?

Tags: css, flexbox

Вот есть такой код. В нём флекс элементы имеют высоту по его содержимому, но при этом расположение элементов растягивается на высоту флекс контейнера, а нужно что бы не растягивалась, вот так

https://prnt.sc/ogcyqe

```css
body {
  height: 200px;

}
.flex {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.elem {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тебе нужен [align-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content): flex-start;

```css
body {
  height: 200px;

}
.flex {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.elem {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
  <div class="elem">Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так странно,  не слышал про это свойство.